# Dynamiclally generate a List-Type form a Object-Type

Tags: typescript-typings, typescript-generics

We developed a little tool that handeles states, similar to a React useReducer, Redux...

There is a set of Action-Definitions with the type of there Payload. Out of this List I have to generate a type with all Action-Types. I think this should by doable by Typescript alone. The only way I can find, is by adding them up manually.

```js
// Action Definition
type ActionDefinition = {
  // Actions Defined, f.e.
  addItem: { value: string }
  updateItem: { key: string, value: string }
  removeItem: { key: string }
  // ...
}

// The Manual generated Type of all Actions
type AllActions = 
  | {
      action: 'addItem'
      payload: { value: string }
    }
  | {
      action: 'updateItem'
      payload: { key: string, value: string }
    }
  | {
      action: 'removeItem'
      payload: { key: string }
    }
```

I can simplify it to the following set:

```js
type Action<Def, Name extends keyof Def> = {
  action: Name
  payload: Def[Name]
}

type AllActions = 
  | Action<ActionDefinition, 'addItem'>
  | Action<ActionDefinition, 'updateItem'>
  | Action<ActionDefinition, 'removeItem'>
  // ...
```

But I still have to list them manually.

What I expect, is something like:

```js
type AllActions = GenerateActions<ActionDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I have a feeling, that it is not the optimal one. So maybe don't accept it to soon.

```
type ActionDefinition = Record<string, any>

type SpecificActionDefinition = {
  addItem: { value: string }
  updateItem: { key: string, value: string }
  removeItem: { key: string }
}

// A little helper that does the same as keyof, but for values
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

// We create an object where the values contain the end result
type GenerateActions<AD extends ActionDefinition> = ValueOf<{
    [Action in keyof AD]: {
        action: Action,
        payload: AD[Action]
    }
}>

type AllActions = GenerateActions<SpecificActionDefinition>;
```